# How to make VB Console Application close itself after specified time

Tags: vb.net

I created a VB console application that runs a series of tasks and I'm planning to set it up in Windows Task Scheduler so it will run by itself based on schedule.. I'd like the exe to close after 30 seconds upon completing its tasks. I'm only familiar with "Console.readline()" where you need to press anything before it closes.. can you help?

```
Sub Main()
    If Directory.Exists(MyPath) Then
        RenameAll(MyPath)
        Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf + vbCrLf + "Press ENTER to exit...")
        Console.ReadLine()
    Else
        Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf + "Path is invalid")
        Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf + vbCrLf + "Press ENTER to exit...")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to close by pressing 'Enter' before the 30 seconds is up?

Comment: If it's running from Task Scheduler, you need none of the output and this code could be reduced to about four lines. Task Scheduler won't read any of the screen output, won't understand whether the path is valid or not, and won't be able to press Enter to exit. Why do you need to delay 30 seconds if Task Scheduler is running it? What is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Actually I want to remove the 'Console.ReadLine()', I just want the console app to close after 30 seconds. I'm planning to setup the exe in Task Scheduler in a daily basis and if my console app won't auto close, there'll be a lot of console apps opened in the screen. Does that makes sense?

Comment: Yes. So as I said, you can remove all of the code that does console output (the `Console.WriteLine`) or waits for input (the `Console.ReadLine`) which leaves about four lines of code (the method declaration, the `if`, the first statement after it, and the `end sub`) and does not require a 30 second delay. So I'll ask again: Why do you want to wait 30 seconds if there is no reason to wait 30 seconds?

Comment: Yeah, I kinda missed the part about using Task Scheduler. In that case, there's no point in any delay at all. The only reason for a delay that I can think of is so that the user can see the output before it closes but if it's run by Task Scheduler then there's no user looking and no point in any console output, thus no point in any delay.

Comment: Hi, there are instances that there will be users using the pc where i will set up the exe. So would like to atleast let the user be informed that the application has ran. The application will display a message of all the folders that are renamed once done

Comment: Again MGM. if this is running from the task scheduler so it's pointless to read the keyboard input. So if I understand your question is you want to show the result of the app after it ran. If nobody pressed a key then your app closes after 30 seconds? If the user isn't fast enough the app will close anyways right? if your app runs every 2 hours and nobody is pressing a key you don't want to end up with 20 windows open. you wouldn't know what is the last one since you aren't doing any timestamp. If leaving a log for your app on the hard drive then i would just create a log file or windows logs

Answer (score 2):

You could replace your lines ..

```
Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf + vbCrLf + "Press ENTER to exit...")
Console.ReadLine()
```

with this.

```
Dim sw As New Diagnostics.Stopwatch
sw.Start()
Console.WriteLine("This console window will close in 30 seconds")
Console.WriteLine("Or press any key")
Do
Loop Until sw.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 30000 Or console.KeyAvailable
```

It creates a stopwatch and keeps looping until either the number of elapsed milliseconds >=30000 or of the user presses a key.

---

Alternatively, if you just want the console to remain open for 30s with no user interaction, replace the lines with

```
Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000)
```